# Insanely high power_cycle_count in ssd - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, ssd

I have a Lenovo T450 laptop which I bought not two months ago. I use Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7. The laptop has an SSD (sdb) and a HDD (sda). I noticed that my ubuntu started hanging a lot lately.

I booted using a liveUSB disk and did a smartctl. Here is the log.
`command : sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb`

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15270881/

I am unable to logon to the sdb at all right now. Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a hardware fault to me: the power on hours are way to low for such a high power cycle count (one power cycle for every 1 minute 25 seconds!)

**Have the SSD swapped if still under warranty!**

Chat logs for any details needed:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27975439#27975439
http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27977527#27977527